# Recyclerview onclicklistener not working

Tags: android

```
recylerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               someMethod();
           }
        });
```

I want to disable click on recylerview items.Here the method `someMethod();` is not called.

Comment: Most straightforward way is to set clickable attribute to false in root layout element of items

Comment: i have set it but its not working.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: set onclick listener for recycler items not to recycler view

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute in your recyclerView in XML file

```
android:clickable="false"
```